# Loading 2gis Map in Android Application

Tags: android, dictionary

I am developing Android app.
I want to use 2gis api. 
But I did not find any controls for show 2gis map in Android application.
Is exists way to show 2gis map in Android Application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript Maps API: http://api.2gis.ru/doc/maps/quickstart/ in your Android application. As an usage example of the 2GIS Maps API look at the Flamp for Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flamp.mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Leaflet library (check the tutorial [Leaflet on Mobile](https://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile/) with [plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) (for example this one [leaflet-2gis](https://github.com/emikhalev/leaflet-2gis))